# Is it possible to set a td align as vertical without using CSS

Tags: html

**Is it possible to set a td align as vertical without using CSS?**

Comment: add property for td valign="middle"

Comment: why don't you want css

Comment: Note that in HTML5 you will **need** to use CSS. See:https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/td.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Answer (score 2):

I know of two ways:

▶ Add **`style = "vertical-align: middle"`** ← Inline CSS

▶ Add **`valign = "middle"`**.

Comment: Technically `style = "vertical-align: middle"` is CSS

Comment: isn't the first method inline styling (css)

Comment: Guys, I think he means without a separate css file. I'm not sure. He just copied the title in the question...

Comment: then internal styling can also be used

Comment: There is no way to tell what the OP means, we can only go on the very vague question it self.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I use it is by using inline css.

```
td style="vertical-align: top;"
```

Comment: Which is still CSS

Comment: Just like you said up above, there's no way to tell what the OP meant.